# How to get the url of a file from aws amplify in dart

Tags: amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

```
 Future<void> queryFileFromStorage(String key) async {
    try {
        final result = await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: key);
        print(result);

        } catch (e) {
        print('Error querying file from storage: $e');
    }
}
```

This is how my function looks to query a file from amplify storage, the type of result object is `Future\<S3GetUrlResult\>`. How do I access the url from this so that I can perform further operations

I want to get the url so that I can use http response to retrieve data.

Comment: in which folder the file is saved in S3

Comment: It is in public/deck/